# SFMC - Add Group Identifier in Automation Studio with SQL Script

Tags: sql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I'm looking to identify subscribers and put them into **buckets** inside a **new data extension**. I have a query to identify the segment I want, but I'm not sure how to move them into a new data extension that contains **an additional column to identify these subscribers** without downloaded the results applying the **bucket name** and uploading manually to a new data extension.

**Ideal Goal: Use Automation Studio to have this automate and refresh data on a schedule.**

**Example:**

I have a Data Extension called **All_Users** with the following fields:

| Field | Type | Primary Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SubscriberKey | Text | X |
| EmailAddress | Text | - |
| FirstName | Text | - |
| LastName | Text | - |
| Age | Text | - |
| Sex | Text | - |
| ZipCode | Text | - |

I have an SQL query that collects the following data:

```
SELECT SubscriberKey, EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName, Age, Sex, ZipCode
FROM [All_Users]
WHERE Age >= '25'
AND AGE < '55'
AND Sex = 'F'
AND LEFT(ZipCode, 5)
IN ('12460','12083','12055','12120','12045','12007','12143')
```

I want to move this data into a new Data Extension, but with an added field to place them into a bucket.

**Example:**

New Data Extension is called **All_Users_By_Bucket**.

| Field | Type | Primary Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SubscriberKey | Text | X |
| EmailAddress | Text | - |
| FirstName | Text | - |
| LastName | Text | - |
| Age | Text | - |
| Sex | Text | - |
| ZipCode | Text | - |
| **BucketName** | Text | - |

**The results** from the query above should insert into this DE, with a BucketName **Group_One**.  Then I want to create more queries to search based on other zip codes and assign them additional bucket names, i.e. **Group_Two**, **Group_Three**, etc... Below would be the ideal table output.

I know I can do this with SQL but in Salesforce Marketing Cloud, **INSERT queries are not supported** from what I understand.

**Fake Data Example:**

```
| EmailAddress          | FirstName | BucketName |
| --------------------- | --------- | ---------- |
| john.smith@email.com  | John      | GroupOne   |
| Harry.smith@email.com | Harry     | GroupOne   |
| Laura.smith@email.com | Laura     | GroupOne   |
| Jason.smith@email.com | Jason     | GroupTwo   |
| Kim.smith@email.com   | Kim       | GroupOne   |
| Sam.smith@email.com   | Sam       | GroupTwo   |
| Kevin.smith@email.com | Kevin     | GroupOne   |
| Dan.smith@email.com   | Dan       | GroupThree |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, this was so simple.  I got my answer from this other post I found.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216871/adding-a-default-value-to-one-column-in-a-sql-activity-used-to-populate-a-de

All I needed to do was past the **Group_Name** as a string and pass it AS the Field Name.

Answer (score 0):

Add this extra default value to your query
**BucketName as GroupOne**
This should work for you, make sure to choose the correct data action when you use the same data extension for multiple automation